# Angular File Upload is being uploaded in all divs while using it inside *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having array of objects in which i'm iterating using `*ngFor`. Here when i'm uploading file inside one div, all other `divs` which are iterated are getting uploaded by the same file. I want to upload the file only for the selected `div`. Below is my code.

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of objects">
  <div class="header-icons-holder">
    <div class="header-icon" (click)="file.click()">upload</div>
    <span style="display:none">
          <input type="file" #file (change)="onChange(file)" multiple>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="fileName">
    <p>{{fileName}}</p>
    <button type="button" (click)="removeFile()">Remove File</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
 toBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
  });

  async onChange(file) {
    this.file = file.files[0];
    this.fileName = file.files[0].name;

    console.log(await this.toBase64(this.file));
  }
  removeFile() {
    this.file = null;
    this.fileName = '';
  }
```

Comment: Typically, click event have a hanlder.  (click)='onClick(filename') where onClick is a function in the Typescript code. Try that first, it allows you to put in a debugger statement so you can see what's happening.

Comment: @JohnPeters I tried using `(click)` it didn't work. `Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.`

Comment: is file a property in your code? I don't understand this file.click()

Comment: @JohnPeters It's just to hide choose image button. I wrapped it inside div and calling it with the reference. So I can put my custom button to click on file

Comment: I think your problem is that you are treating fileName as something that should be independant for each, is this what you are basing the multiple upload assumption off? Because with your current code, you could upload any file to any one of your file upload points and it would assign that files name to the fileName variable. You then have every iteration of your loop listening for changes in that fileName value using your `*ngIf="fileName"` i think you need to use a different variable for each iteration or a similar alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in these two lines of code:

```
this.file = file.files[0];
this.fileName = file.files[0].name;
```

You are having two global variables and using those variables for all the items in objects array. Even though you are uploading a file for one control, it looks on the UI as though you are uploading files to all the control.

I have created this [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/file-upload-in-ng-for) for you which fixes your issue.

#### What have I done?

I have basically ensured that your file upload control is interacting with a specific item in the object instead of updating values globally.

Comment: My backend object doesn't have ` uploadedFile: null,
      fileName: null`. So how Can i do that?

Comment: Makes sense, In that case, I clone the objects I get from backend and add the new attributes I want to use on the frontend.
I updated the stackbliz accordingly for you to understand.

Comment: Hello Harish. Is there any way to add a button in each `div`, so that the user can upload as many files he wants.